# How to save json data in bigtable?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

I have large nested json data and need to save it in bigtable.
suppose my json will be like :

```
{
    "Meta": {
    "Model": "abc",
        "Event": "Arr",
        "Test": true,
        "Source": {
            "ID": "7532568798",
            "Name": "User1"`enter code here`
        },
        "Destinations": [
            {
                "ID": "af09uu0887",
                "Name": "User2"
            }
        ],
        "Message": {
            "ID": 5565
        },
        "FacilityCode": null
    },
    "Demographics": {
        "FirstName": "ABC",
        "MiddleName": null,
        "LastName": "XYZ",
        "DOB": "1982-07-24",
        "Sex": "Female",
        "MaritalStatus": "Married",
        "PhoneNumber": {
            "Home": "+18000000",
            "Office": "+178989009",
            "Mobile": "+190000000"
        },
        "EmailAddresses": [
            "ABC.XYZ@test.net"
        ],
        "Language": "en",
        "Citizenship": [],
        "Address": {
            "StreetAddress": "4762  Street",
            "City": "Unknown",
            "State": "Unknown",
            "ZIP": "53566",
            "County": "Unknown",
            "Country": "Unknown"
}
    }
}
```

Should i have to flatten the json and use diff column qualifiers and save it in bigtable  or is it feasible to save json as it is?

Comment: How will you be using the data? If you will always be reading and writing the entire json string then just store it as is in a single column. If you need to read or update just a part of it at a time, then it might make sense to flatten the json into columns.

Comment: @GaryElliott – please convert your comment into an answer.